# Count duplicate, two-element lists within ArrayList (Groovy)

Tags: list, groovy, nested-lists

I have a list of two-item lists:

```
def list = [[key1, value1], [key1, value1], [key2, value1], [key2, value2], ...]
```

I am trying to write Groovy code which will take "list" and return another list, which displays not only the frequency of each duplicate, two-item list, but also if there are items which are unique:

```
def newList = [[key1, value1:2], [key2, [value1:1, value2:1]], ...];
```

The reasoning behind this format is because I'd write more code to throw an error if a specific "key" had more than one "value". If there is an easier way to do this, any help/suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It normally helps if you show what you've tried when asking a question here...

In this case though, you just need:

```
def result = list.groupBy { it[0] }
                 .collect { k, v -> [k, v.countBy { it[1] }] }
```

And result will equal:

```
[['key1', ['value1':2]], ['key2', ['value1':1, 'value2':1]]]
```

You could also do something like this:

```
def result = list.groupBy { it[0] }
                 .collectEntries { k, v -> [k, v*.getAt(1).unique().size() ] }
```

To give you:

```
['key1':1, 'key2':2]
```

Comment: I don't normally post questions, so going forward I'll post what I've tried, good advice. I knew .groupBy() would be in there somewhere, thanks for the answer.

Comment: @TheRumpler, if that helps, you need to consider [accepting answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).